# Opaque pointer valgrind

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, tree

I'm currently writing a binary tree structure with Opaque Pointer. However, I have Invalid writes with Valgrind.

**Tree.c :**

```
struct node{
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right, *parent;
};

NODE nodeInit(void)
{
    NODE tree = (NODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    tree->key = -1;
    //Error with the 3 lines below
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->parent = NULL;
    return tree;
}
```

**Tree.h :**

```
typedef struct node* NODE;
```

**Note :** I mustn't change the header file.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating memory for *just* the pointer.

typedef struct node* NODE means that from now on `NODE` is an alias for *"a pointer to `struct node`"*. Thus `malloc(sizeof(NODE))` allocates `sizeof struct node *` bytes of memory - enough memory to hold a pointer to your structure, not enough to memory to contain your structure.

Use either:

```
NODE tree = malloc(sizeof *tree);
```

or

```
NODE tree = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
```

The former is perhaps better, because it implicitly means *"allocate enough memory to contain that which is pointed to by the pointer `tree`"*.

---

P.S., [do not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

```
NODE tree = (NODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE)); this line is incorrect.
```

It should be

```
NODE tree = (NODE) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```